# How to position external shout-box?

Tags: html, css

I am adding a shout-box to my page using JavaScript `<script></script>` tags, and I really cannot figure out how to add style to it. The shout-box also goes behind the everything. Here is my website: [link](http://westagario.no-ip.org/)

The following is the shout-box I want to add it:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www4.yourshoutbox.com/shoutbox/start.php?key=521659178"></script>
```

Comment: Add your HTML and CSS code.

Comment: @Maihan Niatt Should i provide you with my index.html?

Comment: Post the code where you have the issue, narrow down you code to the problem. Also create fiddle if you can.

Comment: @Maihan Niatt Well, all i did is tryed adding the script above to my index file but its hidden behind everything and i dont know how to position and bring to front of page (sorry im new to this)

Comment: Post your `index.html` here jsfiddle.net, and I will revise your question.

Comment: @Maihan Niatt https://jsfiddle.net/41g0mc5a/1/

Comment: The HTML structure of your `index.html` is invalid. Please correct the starting and ending tags for HTML elements. And try to separate CSS and JS. It is really hard for someone to debug it.

Comment: And what do you mean by "behind everything"?

Comment: That index file is the exact index file I have

Comment: All I need to know is how do I position the shout box

Comment: I revised your question, and now I am working on solution.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to put your `<script></script>` inside the `div` and then apply the style for it. The `z-index` will help you to bring the content in front of others.

```
<div id="myshoutbox">
   <script></script>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
#myshoutbox {
    z-index:9999;
}
```

You can apply other styles you require.